# Gogs server is throwing SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate while doing git clone

Tags: https, gogs

I have installed gogs and configured https. https url is loading in the browser without any warning. When I try to clone it in my local I am getting "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". Can someone please help me on this?